# Storing values from an array into a register (Assembly)

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64, long-integer

I have an array of longs (size 4) and I want to store each of those 4 values into its own separate register. But I'm not sure how to do this because I've never worked with arrays in assembly. For example, I want to store `array[0]` into `r9`, `array[1]` into `r10`, etc. Can someone help me in doing this? Here is my code so far. `lhs` is the pointer to the array.

```
define(lhs,%rdi)
define(rhs_d,%esi)
define(rhs,%rsi)
define(result,%rdx)

.text


.globl addBignumInt
    .type   addBignumInt, @function
addBignumInt:
.LFB18:
    .cfi_startproc
    # code goes here
    movslq  rhs_d, rhs

    .cfi_endproc
.LFE18:
    .size   addBignumInt, .-addBignumInt
```

So, essentially what I want to do is
    `movq    lhs[0], %r9`
but obviously this isn't correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to offset the pointer pointing to the array (its beginning) by n times sizeof(type) it holds.

So you would do something like this:

```
mov rax, arrBegin ; rax points to the array of longs
```

then the following will store 2nd element in rbx:

```
mov rbx, [rax + 4]
```

or, if you want to access nth element (possibly in loop even though you need to expand manually if you always want to change the destination register), then:

psuedo-code (you can do this however you like, either use the multiply add addressing mode or a helper register):

```
mov dest, [rax + n * 4]
```

where n is either a helper or scale{2, 4, 8} (part of the addressing mode).

Comment: so if lhs is the pointer to the array arr1, and I do
    movq [arr1], rbx
it will store the first value of the array arr1 into rbx?
and 
    movq [arr1 + 4], rax
will store the second value into rax?

Comment: @user2976670 lhs is destination in my case (intel syntax), basically, you store the beginning address of the array in a register and then dereference with offset to access nth element.

Comment: okay, so if I wanted to move a value (e.g. 8) back into the second spot in the array would I do
mov [rax + 4], $8?

Comment: yes, you would, syntax dependent on the assembler you're using, the general idea of an array is: get(array, Nth) returns *(&array + N * sizeof(typeTheArrayHolds))

Comment: so, in your example, what is arrBegin? Is that just lhs in my case?

Comment: @user2976670 it's the address of the very first byte of your array, the beginning of the array in other words